# How to assign a Windows service least privileges to provision new accounts

Tags: windows, security, powershell

We have a Windows service which currently runs as LOCAL_SYSTEM - effectively a local administrator. One of the functions of the service is to provision new local accounts and add them to a specific group. Are the following possible?

1. Use a specific user account / group for the service account and assign privileges to it such that it may create new accounts.
2. Limit the service so it may only create users with limited privileges. For example the accounts that the service provisions, do not have interactive logon, and are members of a specific group.
3. Configure this with PowerShell.

I'd assumed something this would be possible through Local Security Policy but it does not appear to be. Adding the service account to Administrators will work, but doesn't help me reduce the service account's privileges.

The whole point of this is so that if the service gets hacked somehow, we can limit the damage - the hacker can only create accounts less privileged than the service account.

Note that this relates to local accounts not domain accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Powershell's [JEA Role Capabilities](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/jea/overview?view=powershell-7) and create a capability that allows the local account to only use commands related to local user management (New-LocalUser, Add-LocalGroupMember) and restrict the allowed parameters in such a way that only low privilege groups are accepted as an argument.

This should get you started:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/jea/role-capabilities?view=powershell-7

Comment: When I looked at PowerShell remoting, I recall that it required the accounts had interactive logon rights and I am trying to do this without those. I could be wrong, it some time ago I looked into it.